# AWS - Different instance Type of AMI then Instance launched using Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have the following flow for Patch update of web app code in AWS
1) An m4.xlarge instance (Patch Instance) in which development team update code at the particular interval.
2) I, then create an AMI and Launch Configuration using that instance.
3) Using newly created Launch Configuration, I update Autoscaling Group to add the new instance(m4.xlarge) with latest AMI.

Now the questions I have are:
1) Can I make my Patch Instance of t2.micro type and make Autoscaling create the new instance with m4.xlarge? This is just for optimization as Patch Instance is underutilized.
2) Any better way for the patch update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can make an AMI of any instance type and use it on a bigger or smaller one.
2. Could you collaborate on what the Development team is patching?

Comment: New changes in Web application Code

Comment: For web applications I would recommend using CI & CD, you could then setup a bootstrap script to pull the build web application from S3 on startup for example.

Comment: @jarnohenneman CI & CD can be used with pre baked AMIs. That's typical for immutable infrastructure setups.

Comment: @jordanm there are a few ways to solve the issue, and every situation can be solved differently, I just throw my 2 cents into the jar...